# How do you create a 1D array from a given 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

If I'm given a 2D array with unknown parameters, I have to combine the rows together to create a 1D String with those values for example:

```
2 3 4 1
8 1 1 2  

returns  

[2341, 8112]
```

How do you convert a 2D array into a 1D array and set it as a String?
This is what I have so far:

```
public static String[] stichEachRow(int[][] matrix)
  {
    int[] answer = new int[1];
    for (int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++)
    {
      for (int c = 0; c < matrix[0].length; c++)
      {
        answer = "[" + matrix[r][c] + ", ";
      }
    }
    return answer + "]";
  }
```

I get errors that say I can't convert from String to an int[]

Comment: Error is quite clear. You created `int[] answer` and later you want to assign to it `answer = "["+..."` which is string. This is wrong on many levels. Try to rethink what you are doing here. What should be actual result of this method? Should it be array? What type of elements should it hold?

Comment: Break your problem down into parts and put these parts in separate functions: 1. How do you concatenate a 1D array of integers into a single integer?  2. How do you repeat this for each row of a 2D array to produce an array of integers?

Comment: Also, read this: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems?cb=1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    String[] sarr = new String[matrix.length];
    for (int n = 0; n < matrix.length; n++) {
        int[] arr = matrix[n];
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i : arr) {
            sb.append(i);
        }
        sarr[n] = sb.toString();
    }
    return sarr;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done using `Stream` by

```
    Stream<Integer> str = Arrays.stream(arr)
                                .map(a -> IntStream.of(a)
                                                   .reduce(0, (r,v)-> r*10 + v));
    int[] res = str.mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
```

The idea is that each `int[]` in the 2d array is reduced to a number and then we convert that from a stream to `int[]`.

The problem in your implementation is that you declare `int[] answer` and then trying to store a `String` in it.

Comment: Also `Arrays.toString` will change `2 3 4 1` into `[2, 3, 4, 1]` not `2341`.

Comment: you are right - thanks for correcting me. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**A Mathematical Approach - no String Manipulation involved**

```
    // Our initial array
    int[][] arr = {{4,1,8,4},{1,2,3,4}};

    // Array to store results
    int[] result = new int[arr.length];

    // Iterate through array
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

        // Determine multiplier for first number
        double multiplier = Math.pow(10, arr[i].length-1);

        // Iteratate through 2d array
        for (int j : arr[i]){

            // add the result of the multiplier times the number in array of interest
            result[i] += (j * multiplier);

            // divide the multiplier by 10
            multiplier = multiplier / 10;
        }       
    }
```

Hope this helps!